# Auto size outer cells in a table?

Tags: javascript, css-tables

I want to make a page which is structured from a table with 9 cells (3 rows, and 3 columns). I want to put a big `div` inside the middle one and I want it to get centered so it looks like a `margin:0 auto` but with a table.

I'm not very sure how I should explain but here is an illustration of what I want the table to look like:

[image]

I'm wondering if I should use Javascript or if there is a way with CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way would be to apply a rule, a la:

```
 /* find the 2nd (middle) cell in the 2nd (middle) row */
.table .row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(2){
   text-align:center;
}
/* find the div in this cell and align it */
.table .row:nth-child(2) .cell:nth-child(2) div{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width:200px; /* example */
}
```

Where `.table`, `.row` and `.cell` are the appropriate classes you're using.

Alternatively...if you're using this for a page layout, how about the below, which has a header, footer and centered, stretching content, no need for tables so should work in legacy browsers.

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/UBBxH/4/)

HTML

```
<section>
    <article></article>
    <header></header>
    <footer></footer>
</section>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}
header, footer, article {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
header {
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    top:0;
}
footer {
    height:90px;
    bottom:0;
    background:green;
}
section {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    background:grey;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
article {
    padding-top:100px;
    padding-bottom:90px;
    margin:0;
    width:500px;
    background:blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```